# Random objects to grid (Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

http://prntscr.com/ixcbym

How to assign, for some points of grid one object from group 'sec'. And for other points, other objects from the same group?

Comment: Please use the Imgur uploader to add images to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from version `2.1`, we have a *Transform Mesh Node* instead of the *Replicate Mesh Node*. First, we create a list with all possible meshes (One can use the *Objects From Group Node* to get all objects in a group and get the meshes from them.), then using the *Random List* node, we generate a list filled with the possible meshes, then meshes are transformed to the required location using the *Transform Mesh Node*. Which results in:

[image: Node Tree]

If it is not required that the output be a single mesh, one can instance a group of empty objects using the *Object Instancer Node* and then copy the meshes from a list filled with possible objects just as we did before. Which results in:

[image: Node Tree 2]

If you want to selectively add an object at some indices, then manual source object list creation is needed. For instance, if one wants to use the object `Cube` for the vertices at indices 0,1,...,9 and 40, 41,...50 and use the object `Icosphere` for the rest, then the object source list can be created as follows:

[image: Node Tree 3]

The *Fill List Node* can be used to fill a list with a certain number of objects, and the *Combine Object List* node can be used to combine multiple lists, so we can combine an object list filled with 10 `Cube` then another filled with 40 `Icosphere` and then another filled with 10 `Cube`. Then we can use the *Fill List Node* to fill the rest of the elements with `Icosphere`.

Comment: Thanks! But how to use some mesh instead of distribute Matrices?

Comment: I founded!  http://prntscr.com/ixsapl

Comment: How to set the position area for the location of an item?

Comment: @SergeyGolubev What do you mean by the "position area"?

Comment: What if I want the objects to be distributed according to the specified parameters. For example, in specific vertex groups or based on the values of some texture.

Comment: @SergeyGolubev You can ask another question for that.

Comment: Ок. Sorry for my eng). How set for grid points 1-10, 50-60 Cube, and for other points Cube.001?

Comment: Use the *Fill List Node* to create a list with 10  objects `Cube` and another one to create a list with 40 objects `Cube.001`, then use the *Combine Lists Node* to combine both lists, where the first list is the one with 10 objects, the second is the one with 40, the third the one with 10 again, then use the *Fill List Node* again to fill the rest with `Cube.001`. Do you want me to update the answer with screenshot or do you understand it as is?

Comment: If it does not make it difficult, throw off the screen

Comment: @SergeyGolubev Edited the answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you. And how to control the arrangement of elements, at the expense of vertex group?
And one more question. How to set colors to elements, so that they would change depending on how close to a specific element the controller is. For example empty

Comment: @SergeyGolubev You are getting into completely different questions. Ask separate questions for those and I will answer them.

Comment: Ok, have done! And how to control the arrangement of elements, at the expense of vertex group?

Comment: @SergeyGolubev I can show you how to do that, but ask a separate question for that. Is there some reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Ok, i have done.

Comment: @SergeyGolubev Why did you unaccept the answer, you have to tell us what you want in order to edit the answers accordingly.

Comment: Thank you lobster. On this topic, I kind of got all the answers. Which were needed at the moment

Comment: @SergeyGolubev Well, then please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

A List or a Switch can be considered

---

- Object List from Group with an Element Selected. You can programmatically determine which index of the list shall be used to select the particular mesh data.

[image]

- Mesh Data List.  Consider a Loop Subroutine to Create the List.

[image]

- 2 items example

[image]

- I assume we are using different versions of BAN Blender Animation Nodes.
- Please inspect and improve to your needs